# EFcore update context after _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I am working with SQL Geography types and since EFCore doesn't support type geography, I need to execute a stored proc to update my entity.

This works well, but when I call the row that has just been updated, Its returning the old value. 
I can see the correct value in the DB. 
Here is some of my code:

```
var FlId = new SqlParameter("@flId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = testModel.Flid ?? SqlInt32.Null };
var OID = new SqlParameter("@oID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = testModel.OID };
var flName = new SqlParameter("@flName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = testModel.FLName };

var result = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("testSchema.spUpsertOFL  @flId, @oID, @flName,
parameters: new[] { FlId , OID , flName });
```

The above code works and performs the upsert, but when I then run a regular query using EFCore, I get back a stale record.

```
var TestQuery = _dbContext.Fl.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FLCode == testModel.Flcode && x.OID == testModel.OID);
```

I tried reloading the context with:

```
 _dbContext.Entry(fl).Reload();
```

But I got an error saying :

"There was an internal error creating the Fl. The instance of entity type 'Fl' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FlID'} is already being tracked."

If I use postman and hit my get endpoint - the correct result returns.

Comment: Can you create a new `dbContext`?

Comment: Could you please provide your models and dbContext configuration and the called stored procedure? Will be the record updated or inserted? Maybe you have an alternate key violation - it could be the reason for the exception.

Comment: use a new DbContext. The lifetime of one instance should not be too long. DbContext instances track all already retrieved instances and will return those until SaveChanges() is called to remove redundant database calls.

Answer (score 0):

Try detaching the entry and then requerying

```
dbContext.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Detached;
entry = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
```

While researching this problem I saw many people say the best course of action is to dispose and create a new dbcontext https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16861

The next most common solution I saw was to call dbContext.Entry(entry).Reload(); This did not work for me because I was changing the type of an entry via a discriminator. Detaching the old entry means when you request it again it pulls from the database instead of the local cache